Podify react native project is not rendering views because of an error
  /**
  * @format
  */
  import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
  import App from './App';
  import { name as appName } from './app.json';

  AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);

it says unexpected '{' on index.js but theres not  opening brace except for the imports
its not rendering my views
I tried debugging running it throught ai nothing

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

this is a react native build so that is all the code in index.js
